# Running out of inodes disk space, free space left on device

Tags: diskspace, linode

I am getting the message 'disk is full' despite having plenty of free space.

**Inodes :-**

```
$ df -i
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1           1638400   55434 1582966    4% /
tmpfs                 480574       1  480573    1% /dev/shm
/dev/xvdb2           3014656 3007131    7525  100% /export
```

**Disk space :-**

```
$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1             25G   16G  9.3G  63% /
tmpfs                 1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvdb2             46G   24G   20G  56% /export
```

Note: we have our magento  application code which is under /dev/xvdb2 /export.please how to sort out the issue.

Comment: Is your application creating a lot of small files?

Comment: @Matt What I guess may be magento cache files are getting generated at this location in large quantity.

Comment: Many filesystems can be created with more Inodes. You should look into documentation of your filesystem (or the formatting utility).

Comment: @RaoulSteffen  I have run the below command. (for i in /*; do echo $i; find $i -type f | wc -l; done)    Result : /export/www/htdocs/service/ExportScripts
2865306

Comment: ExportScripts folder had a lot of files that were taking up the inodes.How can i re-index the ExportScripts directory